# Regular Expression - remove digits if surrounded by square brackets

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression statement that should remove digits and square brackets that are preceding and following the digits.
For example if the input text is:

```
"William Henry Gates III  (born October 28, 1955) is an American software developer and philanthropist [2][3]."
```

Then the output text should be:

```
"William Henry Gates III  (born October 28, 1955) is an American software developer and philanthropist".
```

If I execute the code:

```
output_txt = re.sub("[\[0-9\]]", "", input_txt)
```

Then the output is:

```
William Henry Gates III  (born October , ) is an American software developer and philanthropist.
```

So the problem is that the regular expression statement doesn't take into account that digits should only then be removed if they are preceded or followed by square brackets.

I have tried to add ^, $ and \ symbols to the statement but so far with no positive result. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: `re.sub(r"\[[0-9]+]", "", input_txt)`

Comment: re.sub("\\[\d\\]", "", input_txt)